# How to share datafram from multiprocess to main process?

Tags: python, sql, dataframe, multiprocessing

Here's the 2nd version coding I'm using now( it's from Booboo), it takes about 17mins to return query result, and data could be transfer to patrent process.

```
from multiprocessing.pool import Pool

def do_query(query):
    conn = cx_Oracle.connect("*", "*", "***", encoding="UTF-8")
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    sql = cursor.execute(query)
    table = cursor.fetchall()
    col = [x[0] for x in cursor.description]
    return pd.DataFrame(table, columns=col)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print('start:',datetime.datetime.now())
    queries = [
        "select aaa from AAA",
        "select bbb from BBB",
        "select ccc from CCC",
        "select ddd from DDD", 
    ]
    pool = Pool(len(queries))
    dataframes = pool.map(do_query, queries)
    pool.close()
    pool.join()
    print('end:',datetime.datetime.now())
```

And below script is my 1st version coding( original version) which I used to query with 4 sub-process, it takes 4~6mins to finish the query, but didnot transfer query data from sub-process to parent.but I can save those data in sub-process.

```
def aquery():
    conn = cx_Oracle.connect("*", "*", "***", encoding="UTF-8")
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    sql = cursor.execute("select aaa from AAA")
    aaa = cursor.fetchall()
    col = [x[0] for x in cursor.description]
    df_aaa = pd.DataFrame(aaa, columns=col)

    
def bquery():
    conn = cx_Oracle.connect("*", "*", "***", encoding="UTF-8")
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    sql = cursor.execute("select bbb from BBB")
    bbb = cursor.fetchall()
    col = [x[0] for x in cursor.description]
    df_bbb = pd.DataFrame(bbb, columns=col)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    print('start:', datetime.datetime.now())
    aaa_process = multiprocessing.Process(target=aaa)
    bbb_process = multiprocessing.Process(target=bbb)

    aaa_process.start()
    bbb_process.start()

    aaa_process.join()
    bbb_process.join()

    print('end:', datetime.datetime.now())
```

So I wonder if the 2nd version coding spend much more time just because it needs time to transfer data from sub-process to parent?

Comment: You must remember that your multiprocessing process is in a completely new Python interpreter in an entirely separate chunk of memory.   You CAN pass stuff back by using something like a `multiprocessing.queue`  Have the main process listen to the queue, and the subprocess can shove stuff in.  The queue module creates a TCP socket to pass information back home.

Comment: dear @ Tim Roberts, I failed to use queue to share datafrme from sub-process to the parent , do you have any idea about this?
thank you in davance.

Comment: How could I possibly know without seeing what you did?

Comment: I indicated in my answer that you might not gain any performance improvement over serial processing, so I am not surprised by your results. I did my own benchmarking (my table is obviously different than yours) and found that serial processing was faster than using multithreading (there is overhead in using multithreading just as there is with multiprocessing even if it is not as much) and multithreading was faster than multiprocessing (much greater overhead). And the way to do multiprocessing is: `from multiprocessing import Pool` and then replace `ThreadPool` with `Pool` in your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your example, which I presume (at least I hope) is just a simplification of what you are really want to accomplish, as presented cannot achieve any performance improvement because you are *not* *effectively* doing any multiprocessing. This is because although your main process creates a subprocess, it then immediately blocks until that subprocess finishes and returns its result and thus there is no parallel computing occurring. All you have accomplished is to add additional overhead by creating a new process and having to transmit data from one address space to another.

So a *real* use case for multiprocessing/multithreading would, for example, involve the situation where you had to do *multiple* queries with each one needing to produce a dataframe from the results. If we were to analyze what is involved in that situation there is the query itself followed by the creation of the dataframe. Since there is the aforementioned overhead in creating new processes and returning data across processes' address spaces, my approach would be to use multithreading for the query, which should work nicely since the issues with competition between threads for the Global Interpreter Lock should not apply since the query task will mostly be in a network wait state. You could then return the results of the query back to the main thread (there is now no inter-process transfer required) and have the main thread do the CPU work of creating the dataframes from the returned data or more simply have the same worker function build the dataframe from the results and return the completed dataframe. In the latter case, depending on whether `pandas` releases the Global Interpreter Lock or not, you may not achieve any level of parallel processing in building the dataframes, but you will not be doing any worse than having the main process build the dataframes.

In the worst-case scenario where `pandas` does not release the Global Interpreter Lock, it is true that you will not be doing the more CPU-intensive work, i.e. the creation of the dataframes, in parallel for which multiprocessing would suggest itself as the solution. But the overhead of multiprocessing only becomes worthwhile when the amount of CPU processing for each task is great enough that what is gained by parallel computing offsets what is lost by the additional overhead. I don't believe that would be the case in this particular situation.

So the following is example code using a multithreading pool for the case where you had two queries to create two dataframes:

```py
from multiprocessing.pool import ThreadPool

def do_query(query):
    conn = cx_Oracle.connect("*", "*","*", encoding="UTF-8")
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    sql = cursor.execute(query)
    table = cursor.fetchall()
    col = [x[0] for x in cursor.description] 
    return pd.DataFrame(table, columns=col)
   
if __name__ == '__main__':
    queries = [
        "select * from I where I.DATE between sysdate - 4 and sysdate - 3",
        "select * from I where I.DATE between sysdate - 5 and sysdate - 4"
    ]
    pool = ThreadPool(len(queries))
    dataframes = pool.map(do_query, queries)
    pool.close()
    pool.join()
```

**It's still not clear whether the above would increase performance over serial code running two successive queries; it would depend on the complexity (running time) of the queries themselves.**

Comment: The Nth dataframe can be referenced with dataframes[N]. This is basic Python list indexing. Also, if my response answers your question, then you should *accept* the answer.

Comment: I am away until Friday and won’t be able to look at this until I return. In the meantime please update your question with the specific code you are referring to.

Comment: I tried many times after change code as your suggestion to use multiprocess pool, but always take time equivalent to sequential execution.
could you share your code? thanks a lot.

Comment: Did you read my comment to your question?  So you should not be using multiprocessing.

Comment: My posted answer shows how the dataframes are returned easily by using a multiprocessing pool. If you use `multiprocessing.Process` instances then you need to pass to each process a `multiprocessing.Queue` instance to which it writes its dataframe. So I have no idea why you say data cannot be transferred from sub-process to parent.

Comment: Yes, your code can return dataframe from sub-process to parent, but I found it always takes much more time than 'parallel run( I mean the second portion code in my question)'. it just looks like 'sequential run' if I only calculate the query time.

But actually I know your code was run as ‘parallel' since I checked the task manager and found 6 PID. the only question is why it takes so long time......

Comment: It takes time to create processes and there is overhead in moving data from one process to another: it has to be serialized and deserialized. This is overhead you do not have with serial processing. Therefore the parallelization function must be sufficiently long-running such that what you gain by parallelization offsets what you lose by the additional overhead. In this case your worker function is too trivial to gain by parallelization.

Comment: I no longer know what "original code" you are now talking about and spending less time than what; what are you comparing? Separate processes means separate memory means MORE TIME to create processes and to move data.

Comment: Well I don't see the "original version" and I don't have a photographic memory. But if the original version was not returning a dataframe by either by writing to a queue explicitly or implicitly (by using a multiprocessing pool and issuing a `return` statement specifying a dataframe).  wouldn't that based on everything I have said explain everything because there is not the overhead of moving data from one process to another?

Comment: I've revised my question again, Boobo, pls check it when you're free.
And I'd like to close our communication loop for this question after today.
Also, if you don't mind, I will delete some comments to let this question more concise for others reviewers.
thanks a lot for your help this time, you've solved a lot of my confusion.

Comment: I really still don't understand what I am supposed to be addressing here. "1st portion code" was either a multithreading pool or multiprocessing pool, the latter not being recommended since moving data from one process to another could be expensive and I did not see much Global Interpreter Lock contention in your code that would make multithreading unwise. "2nd portion code" was your creating sub-processes, which I have **stated repeatedly** never moved data from one process to another (and therefore was totally *useless*) so it would have to run faster than my multiprocessing pool version.